# Dynamic Library for Python compilation - no directory

Tags: python, c, gcc, swig

Hopefully this will be a simple one. I'm reading book called Beginning Python and learning how you can make extensions using c or c++ and then use swig to make it available to several languages. I've run through an example of a palindrome checking bit of c code. Hopefully I won't Need to include all the code. When it comes to compilation and linking:

```
gcc -dynamic -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/include/python2.7 -c palindrome.c

gcc -dynamic -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/include/python2.7 -c palindrome_wrap.c
```

If I do these commands as the book says I don't see any visible problem, however there is something wrong with the next step:

```
gcc -dynamiclib palindrome_wrap.o palindrome.o -o _palindrome.so -Wl, -undefined, dynamic_lookup
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: dynamic_lookup: No such file or directory
```

The example I'm running through is from the textbook word for word and it's a beginners book, naturally I'm stumped only just learning about using c and c++ to make libraries for other languages. I suspect it's probably that something has changed regards files or directories on the mac since the book was written (I picked mac to learn this since it's closer to unix than windows). Compilation steps still look rather arcane to me so hopefully someone know what is wrong here.

Thanks,

Ben W.

Comment: maybe `dynamic_lookup` needs a directory behind it like `.`

Comment: I got the same `dynamic_lookup: No such file or directory` error which is how I found this post.  Turns out I was accidentally compiling for MacOS on my Linux machine!  Hence it was using compiler options for "Darwin".  Now that I am compiling for a target platform of Linux or "posix", I'm fine.

Answer (score 0):

gcc option ends with no comma, "-Wl -undefined dynamic_lookup". At least it works for me.